# Minimum page margins

Tags: printer, margins

How do I found out what the minimum page margins for my printer is? (I do not have a manual).

I got a Canon MG5150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Step 1:** [Google](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Canon+MG5150+page+margins&qscrl=1#sclient=psy&hl=nl&qscrl=1&source=hp&q=Canon+MG5150+margin&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=1&cad=b).
2. **Step 2:** Click on the [official Canon website](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5150.aspx?faqtcmuri=tcm:13-774214&page=1&type=faq).

Apparently, the printer supports borderless printing, although some cropping might occur. Using default settings, the following applies:

```
Size Printable Area (width x height) Letter
8.00 x 10.69 inches / 203.2 x 271.4 mm Legal*
8.00 x 13.69 inches / 203.2 x 347.6 mm
```

Or, of course, you could just have printed a test page using the smallest possible margin :)

Lastly, you can simply [download](http://support-au.canon.com.au/P/search?model=PIXMA%20MG5150&filter=0&menu=Manual) the manual was well.

Comment: Why would I do all that when you found the answer for me? Seems crazy ;) I look at it this way: You got 35 points (at least by SO counting) for answering a simple question = you owe me, hehe.